# IF/ELSE logic in WinSCP script

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, winscp

I have a simple script to move perform some maintenance operations on the remote Unix SFTP host, but would like to do all of the operations only if some of the files exist on the windows server. Here is example of the simple code I use, and was wondering if WinSCP supports "if exist " windows command:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp://user@ftp.server.com -hostkey="xxxxxx" - privatekey=\\location

delete file.txt

rename file1.txt

put file0.txt file.txt

etc...

exit
```

Would be nice to do all of the above if I could do something like this:

```
if exist (\\windows server\filename.txt
    .....
)
```

Have to mention that execution is performed using `WinSCP.com`.

Comment: Can you use an actual batch file to call the winscp script file?  There is definitely a batch-file command to check for existence of a file.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ian suggested in comments, you do not need the if-then logic in the WinSCP script for this. Just use the `if` command in wrapper batch file like:

```
@echo off
if exist \\windows_server\filename.txt winscp.com /script=script.txt
```

Had you really needed to use if-then logic in WinSCP code, see WinSCP article [Conditional Processing in Automation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation_conditional).

Further reading:

- [WinSCP .NET Assembly and COM Library](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library)
- WinSCP article [Checking file existence](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_checking_file_existence)